# What does double slash (//) directory mean in robots.txt?

Tags: linux, home-directory

You will get the following output with:

```
curl https://www.ibm.com/robots.txt
```

I delete many lines, keeping only part of it.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: //
Disallow: /account/registration
Disallow: /account/mypro
Disallow: /account/myint

# Added to block site mirroring
User-agent: HTTrack
Disallow: /
#
```

I understand that `/` means root directory, but what does double slash `//` directory mean here in `robots.txt`?

Comment: It could be a typo, I can't find a single reference to a double slash in any of the official Robot Exclusion documents.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Typo or a coding fluke made by an automated system generating a `robots.txt` on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a mistake:

```
Disallow: //
```

The thing is that the `robots.txt` spec—[as outlined here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)—clearly states:

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".

But some people claim that is not the case [such as this site that states that Google can handle pattern matching](https://searchengineland.com/a-deeper-look-at-robotstxt-17573):

> **Pattern matching**: At this time, pattern matching appears to be usable by the three majors: Google, Yahoo, and Live Search. The value of pattern matching is considerable. Let’s look first at the most basic of pattern matching, using the asterisk wildcard character.

But regardless of that, the `//` means a literal directory of a directory with no name attached to that directory since there is no wildcard (`*`) globbing or anything there. And `//` just seems odd.

My guess is it’s a mistake of some sort. Yes, an IBM webmaster can make mistakes! But I would also guess that the `robots.txt` is automatically generated by some system and somehow a path such as `/*/` was converted to `//` when the `robots.txt` was automatically generated by the system.

Comment: Either that, or the entry is there specifically to prevent mistake URLs with a redundant slash from being indexed.

Comment: @grawity Fair enough but I am not too sure what the benefit would be to have a URL that is `example.com//thing` as some odd method of obscuring data from crawlers.